# C# display html code control needed

Tags: c#

I'm looking for a control that be able to show HTML code like shown is the following image:

[image]

I just need to show the HTML code loaded and display it without any edition.

I do not find it anywhere.

Any help?

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking, are you looking for a tool that will allow you to pass a url and return the html that belongs to that url.

Are you asking how something like that gets created in ASP.net?
What are you trying to accomplish and with what type of application? Web-based or Client based?

Comment: Is this Win Forms? Where is the HTML coming from?

Comment: I get the html code from a URL using HttpWebRequest, so I just want to be able to display the HTML received like shown in the image. As if it were a textarea. @JimW Yes, it's winforms.

Comment: So it's the coloured syntax highlighting that's the tricky bit?  Otherwise the answer is just stick a TextBox in a Form with a close button.

Comment: I do not mind it's colored the syntax. Just need the HTML code be spannable for displaying it like the image.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the info you've provided;

1. Create a new Form
2. Add a Close button to it
3. Add a TextBox and set it to ReadOnly
4. Set the .Text property in the TextBox to the HTML to show.

If you do want syntax highlighting, check for open source projects on GitHub or articles on codeproject.com

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a WinForm and a text box called txHTML to display the text, and a textbox called txUrl to provide the url you want the html from. Put this on a button click event to fill your txHTML with what you desired.

```
protected void Get_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){

HttpWebRequest wr = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(txUrl.Text);

// get the response
HttpWebResponse WebResp = (HttpWebResponse)wr.GetResponse();
string res = "";

using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(WebResp.GetResponseStream()))
{
    res = sr.ReadToEnd();
    sr.Close();
}

WebResp.Close();

txHTML.Text = res;

}
```